# Not exist in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, postgresql-9.1

Im using postgres db, I'm trying to execute below SQL to insert into table where not exist

I want to insert data into table before that I want to check whether it exists or not if it exists then don't insert otherwise.

I want my query to be simplified as I'll be using it my python code with pycopg2 library

```
INSERT INTO T1 (a1, a2, a3, a4)
VALUES (123, '20e16411-b8f7', 4, (SELECT u1 from T2 where u2 = 'test@test.com'))
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a3 
                  FROM TI 
                  WHERE a1 =123 
                    AND a2 = '20e16411-b8f7' 
                    AND a3 = 4 
                    AND a4 = (SELECT u1 from T2 where u2 = 'test@test.com'))
```

`SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE" Position: 236`

I'm getting issue on where syntax, however I'm not sure is it the right query to achieve my logic, if it's not kindly correct my query as well

```
If not exist (select * from t1 where <check>)
Begin
Insert
End
```

Comment: help us help you - share the error you're getting

Comment: I have updated the question with error

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `insert ... select`:

```
insert into t1 (a1, a2, a3, a4)
select 123, '20e16411-b8f7', 4, u1
from t2 
where 
    u2 = 'test@test.com'
    and exists (
        select a3 
        from t1 
        where 
            t1.a1 = 123 
            and t1.a2 = '20e16411-b8f7' 
            and t1.a3 = 4 
            and t1.a4 = t2.u1
    )
```

Comment: I have edited my question with better clarification

Comment: @user9185088: I think this query does what you want.

Comment: No it doesn't worked for me, it's like first want to check if data exists if not then insert

Comment: I have updated the if not sample request what I want to achieve

Comment: I think you have to change AND EXISTS and AND NOT EXISTS.

Answer (score 0):

Let the database validate the uniqueness.  Define a unique constraint on the columns you care about:

```
create unique index unq_t1_a1_a2_a3_a4 on t1(a1, a2, a3, a4);
```

Then use `on conflict`:

```
insert into T1 (a1, a2, a3, a4)
    select 123, '20e16411-b8f7', 4, t2.u1
    from T2
     where t2.u2 = 'test@test.com'
    on conflict (a1, a2, a3, a4) do nothing;
```

Comment: I don't have access to create or modify table

Comment: @user9185088 . . . If these columns should be unique, then you should request that the data be changed to support this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use WHERE after VALUES thats why it gives error, in this query you have to use SELECT instead of VALUES, something like that;

```
INSERT INTO T1 (a1, a2, a3, a4)
SELECT 123, '20e16411-b8f7', 4, (SELECT u1 from T2 where u2 = 'test@test.com')
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT a3 
              FROM TI 
              WHERE a1 =123 
                AND a2 = '20e16411-b8f7' 
                AND a3 = 4 
                AND a4 = (SELECT u1 from T2 where u2 = 'test@test.com'))
```